# Skipping deploy due to sync error:copying files: running error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found (\\\"auth\\\")

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

kubenrnetes deployment auth file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1 
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: nadavirinchi/auth
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: "1"
---



apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata: 
    name: auth-srv
  spec:
    selector:
      app: auth
    ports:
      - name: auth
        protocol: TCP
        port: 3000
        targetPort: 3000
```

skaffold.yaml file

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts: 
    - image: nadavirinchi/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync: 
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
```

error:

syncing 1 files for nadavirinchi/auth:115169219879631443c11fc8c0d683d0d36bba795251c64884094aa92a771735
time="2021-11-09T16:18:20+05:30" level=warning msg="Skipping deploy due to sync error:copying files: running [kubectl --context docker-desktop exec auth-depl-99888fc4b-vcc2c --namespace default -c auth -i -- tar xmf - -C / --no-same-owner]\n - stdout: ""\n - stderr: "error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found (\"auth\")\n"\n - cause: exit status 1" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop

running command:
skaffold dev

Comment: When exactly are you getting this error? Which command are you running? Please make your [example reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MikolajS. the command i ran was skaffold dev in the app.listen of index.ts file i was supposed to get listening on 300 but instead after watch for changes i only get o.of packges installed and the vulnerabilities and npm fund all of that... if i make any changs ti ibdex.ts file i get the above error